# Reset screen saver settings on timer or on load

Tags: macos, screensaver

My company changes my screensaver settings to some default they want. I want to keep my settings, so I would like to change the settings either on a timer or on login back to the settings I have chosen.

Can someone suggest the best method for doing this? Every day I come in my screen saver settings have been reset

I run OS X Yosemite.

When i set it in screensaver settings I get the following from

`defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver`

```
{
    CleanExit = YES;
    PrefsVersion = 100;
    idleTime = 600;
    moduleDict =     {
        moduleName = Shell;
        path = "/System/Library/Screen Savers/Shell.qtz";
        type = 1;
    };
    moduleName = XXXXXX;
    modulePath = "/System/Library/Screen Savers/Flurry.saver";
}
```

I XXXXX'ed out the moduleName because it's set by the company

Comment: Is it daily or weekly event ?

Comment: It happens on a daily basis

Comment: tell us what is the screensaver you want to use ?     defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change screen saver with applescript:

```
tell application "System Events" to set current screen saver to screen saver "Flurry"
```

Replace `"Flurry"` with the screen saver you prefer. You then need to use the many available ways to execute the code when necessary.

Comment: I want to set the screen saver.

Comment: @sylvanaar then this is the code.

Comment: Unfortunately It does not work

Comment: The change is not reflected in System Preference. You can test it by Terminal: `open -a /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app`

Answer (score 0):

To automate the changing of the ScreenSaver one can use the Automator and a script command.

Open the Automator and create a workflow. Now drag the Calendar new event to the right and choose date/time. (you can change the Date/Time and the repeating occurrence later in the calendar app.

Next drag the "Run AppleScript" to the right and paste following in it between the * *

```
tell application "System Events" to set current screen saver to screen saver "Shell"
```

Save your workflow:

[image: screensaver]

Replace "Shell" with one of following options of your choosing:

[image: options]

Open calendar and adjust that event, and make it repeating, so from now on you will have a automatic screen saver change.

Comment: I was looking to change the screen saver